# Trying to install DBD::mysql using macports mysql and perl fails make test [Snow Leopard]

Tags: mysql, perl, macos

I have recently installed mysql5 and perl5 through macports in order to try and subvert an earlier issue of running perl script architecture discrepancies (introduced as of OSX10.6).

Downloaded the DBD::mysql package and seek to manually install it.

perl Makefile works well, as does make.

make test, however, yields the following:

```
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /opt/local/bin/perl5 "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0,     'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00base....................ok 1/6                                           
#   Failed test 'use DBD::mysql;'
#   at t/00base.t line 21.
#     Tried to use 'DBD::mysql'.
#     Error:  Can't load '/Users/ianseyer/Downloads/DBD-mysql-    4.011/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql:     dlopen(/Users/ianseyer/Downloads/DBD-mysql-4.011/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 2):     Symbol not found: _is_prefix
#   Referenced from: /Users/ianseyer/Downloads/DBD-mysql-    4.011/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
#   Expected in: dynamic lookup
#  at (eval 7) line 2
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 7) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 7) line 2.
t/00base....................NOK 2/6FAILED--Further testing stopped: Unable to load     DBD::mysql
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: why not use the CPAN shell to install modules? http://search.cpan.org/~andk/CPAN-1.9402/lib/CPAN.pm

Answer (score 1):

I would start by trying to install the macports version of DBD::mysql:

```
sudo port install p5-dbd-mysql
```

If that doesn't work, try cpanm:

```
cpanm -S DBD::Mysql
```

Only use manual installation as a last resort.